# Android studio mysql server timed out/refused connection

Tags: java, android, mysql, server

I'm currently attempting to connect android studio to my sql server but had no luck, I then tried to connect to my local mysql database and I'm getting the exact same error, this is what it looks like:

E/Database: Network error IOException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 1433) from /:: (port 54516): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Here's a snippet of my code:

jdbc:jtds:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase,java,password

When it comes to the ip string I've tried just about everything such as 10.0.0.2 or using my actual ipv4 address but I still get the same error.

```
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection openConnection() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        String ip = "localhost";
        String db = "javabase";
        String un = "java";
        String password = "password";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + "/" + db+ ";user=" + un + ";password=" + password + ";";
        Log.d("Database", "Attempting to establish connection to database server...");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        Log.d("Database", "Connection to " + con.getMetaData().getURL());
        return con;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Database", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is incorrect. Connection string is to be that:
String connURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un+ ";password=" + password;